# how to run core php file along with codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a website developed in codeigniter framework, I also need my API to be placed on the server but outside the codeigniter setup [same root path].

Problem:
My website is working just fine [codeigniter] but my api's are throwing Internal server error [500]. I am sure it is related to htaccess rule which is written in codeigniter but I dont know how to fix that.

Thx
VN

My htaccess code for api folder

```
RewriteBase/api-v1/
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?request=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

My htaccess code for codeigniter

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Comment: add `RewriteRule ^api-v1(/|$) - [L]`  above the other rewrite rules in the main .HTACCESS, if `api-v1` is in a subfolder within the path of the main HTACCESS.  What it does is if the URL starts with `api-v1` and ends with a `/` or end of string, it bails out of the rewrite rules `[L]`, so that they wont apply to that folder.

Comment: 500 is just a general error, that could be anything.... so there are probably other things going on too, I would also check for error log files etc...